# Apply classes to all succeeding Responsive screen using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

How to use tailwind's theme screen in such a way that if a div has

```
<div className ="2xl:text-black" /> 
//(text-black should apply on 3xl,4xl and so on)
```

it should **automatically** applied on **2xl as well as 3xl or any screen greater than 2xl screen** width.

The idea is to apply same class to all the succeeding screens without mentioning all the  screens (3xl/4xl/..). Also keeping in mind, that the default behavior should not get disturbed i.e. if the succeeding screen is specified in the class it should apply only to that specific screen like below -

```
<div className ="2xl:text-black 3xl:text-white" /> 
//(4xl,5xl should take text-white)
```

Current Tailwind Config -

```
theme: {
    screens:{
            ...,
            '2xl':{
                   'min': '1536px',
                   'max': '3200px'
                  },
            '3xl':{
                   'min': '3201px',
                   'max': '1536px',
      }
}
```

Comment: don't use max values for the queries just a min value so that a higher query overwrites the others. That way the lower query will remain active until it is actively overwritten (mobile-first approach).